# Kafka Streams KStream conversion

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I understand you can use the `process` or `transform` methods to specify custom behavior.

I want to pass each `KStream` message value to a separate Java method.  Is it possible to convert the `KStream` message value into a `String` that I can pass to my Java method?

I can't find anything on converting the `KStream` message to a different type so I can pass it to a method.

Comment: It depends on your value type, using `KStream::mapValues`, `KStream::map` you can transform to new value/value type (https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#mapValues-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapperWithKey-, https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#map-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper-)

Comment: I don't want to transform the value within the KStream, I want to convert the KStreams value into a different String object that I can pass to a java method

Comment: Using Kafka Streams is mostly about transforming keys and/or values.

Comment: I'm aware but you can implement process or transform methods to include custom logic and you can also implement processor api

Comment: Not sure what you want to do. Maybe `stream.foreach(...)` and call a method for each input record? You could convert the value type to String on-the-fly. How to convert the value to String type depends on the value type. The simplest thing would be to call `toString()`.